# How to dilute 5000 ppmvol of $\mathrm{CO}_2$ to obtain 250 ppm with a fluxmeter?

Tags: experimental-physics, physical-chemistry, gas

My problem is that I have a tank, containing $\mathrm{CO}_2$ at 5000 ppmvol, Oxygen $21\%$ vol and Nitrogen the rest, connected with a mass flow controller (flux max at $150$ ml/min). And I have a tank of air (Oxygen and Nitrogen) that can be fluxed at a max of $1000$ ml/min.

I need to dilute $\mathrm{CO}_2$ to obtain a final flux of $250$ ppm of $\mathrm{CO}_2$ at 1000 ml/min.

I don't understand which values I have to set on the mass flux controller for each of the two tanks. Might you explain to me also the calculation, please?

Comment: Are there any constraints on the concentration of gas components other than CO2?  If so, these need to be accounted for.

Comment: @DavidWhite no, there are not

Answer (score 1):

Reducing 5000 ppm to 250 ppm would mean 5000 divided by 20 equals 250, so 1/20th of 5000 equals 250, which equals 5% of 5000. So your final flow mix would be 5% carbon dioxide mix to 95% air, or 50 ml/min of carbon dioxide mix and 950 ml/min of air to total 1000 ml/min at 250 ppm of carbon dioxide. (Note that this does not include any carbon dioxide that may be in the compressed air.)

Comment: This way, am I not considering 2 times the dilution on CO2? I mean, the tank of carbon dioxide already contains air (it is a mix of CO2 and air) and I add more air from the air tank. For the dilution, should I consider the original air mixed with CO2?

Comment: If the tank of air, oxygen and nitrogen,  does not contain CO2 then the mix I stated is correct.

Comment: @Mrs.Peacock, and if that tank of air has the standard 415 ppm of CO2 in it that the atmosphere does, you CAN'T dilute down to 250 ppm of CO2 in the mixed stream.

Comment: The tank of air doesn't contain CO2.   In both cases (@AdrianHoward and my previous comment) I should digit 50ml/min for the flowrate of the CO2-air tank (MFC-1) and 950ml/min for the flowrate of the air tank (MFC-2). This way, I obtain a total of 1000 ml/min.   So, to calculate the ppm of CO2, if I apply this formula: 5000ppm*(50ml/min : 950ml/min) I will obtain a higher concentration of CO2 (even if I am consider that in the 50 ml/min I have also air, that it is right). Sorry, but I don't understand why it is wrong.

Comment: Mixing 5% of gas with 5000 ppm CO2 with 95% of gas with no CO2 will yield gas with 250 ppm of CO2. Nornal air in the atmosphere contains traces of other gasses besides oxygen and nitrogen including CO2

Answer (score 0):

If I have $10$ ppm of $\mathrm{CO_2}$ and I need to make it to $1$ ppm, then how much volume of air is required to dilute it in ml/min and for what time?